# Facebook account converted as advert page

Tags: facebook

I have a normal Facebook account and for the last 4 months whenever I try to open it, I am getting an advertisement page and there are no options or settings available for changing it to my personal timeline.

How can I get back to my normal account?

[image: screen shot]